# How to make Outlook select the last conversation after changing folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

When I collapse all conversations in my Inbox, then go to another folder in Outlook and then come back to my Inbox, Outlook does not select the last conversation. How to change this behavior?
I am using Office 365 ProPlus Version 1708
Thank you.

Comment: Do you need the last selected conversation or just the most recent one?

Comment: Either would be fine for me.